# strong pointer to UIlabel is not pointing to correct label when offscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UITableView` with a prototype cells that I have created using IB. I have a `UILabel` in this prototype cell. I have set the tag value of 5 to this `UILabel` so that I can identify it using `viewForTag:` method.
I have also defined 20 private property like this

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label_1;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label_2;
.
.
.
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label_20;
```

Now, while creating cell from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I am assigning `UILabel` of each row to the corresponding property (label_1 for row 1, label_2 for row 2,... etc.) using `self.label_1 = (UILabel*)[cell viewForTag:5];//5 is the Tag value i have setup using IB`.

Everything is fine till now. Now, when I run this app, i see that properties till 16 has proper values, rest are null. This is because only the first 16 cell has been drawn so remaining properties are still not have been assigned the corresponding `UILabel`.
Everything is fine till here. Now when I scroll the table so that remaining 4 cells are on screen and first 4 cells goes offscreen. now, when i print (using `NSLog(@"%@",self.label_1.text)`.) the value of each property, I found, the properties whose corresponding labels are on screen outputs correct value, whereas, those which are offscreen outputs random values (not null, just random values, can be off other properties too.)

In normal scenario the first thing came to my mind is as soon as the rows goes offscreen they are deallocated and hence the properties are now pointing to some random location (dangling pointer). But here in my case, properties are `strong` so the corresponding UILabel should not b deallocated till this pointer exist. Can anybody please explain whats happening here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to save memory, `UITableView` recycles `UITableViewCells`. You are recycling cells when you call `tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

My guess is that `label_1 == label_17`, `label_2 == label_18`, etc.

If you need to update these labels, you need to rethink your design. All of the updates need to be done in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. When you need to update the data in the cells, you need to call `[tableView reloadData]`, and set the correct value of the label within the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of your `UITableViewDataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Cells are being reused. Let's say 10 cells can fit one screen. When you scroll down, first cell will disappear, eleventh will appear, and so on. Instead of creating new view for each cell, tableview keeps a queue and dequeues the cells from it. It means that your cell in fifth row could also be used to display the sixteenth row or any other row. You don't actually know, or have control of the cell view(and it's subviews) when it goes off screen, and you shouldn't keep strong pointers to views in dynamic cells. If your cells were static, it'd be completely fine. Instead, move your logic to tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. That way, you know that cell with certain indexPath has appeared on screen and you can act accordingly.